# How to play video in my player from gallery in android?

Tags: android

I am developing Video Player in which i want to set my player at launcher, so user can play video in my player from gallery for that:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3gp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3GP" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*mp4" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MP4" />
</intent-filter>
```

when I set this things in manifest then it show my player at video player launcher

**My Problem is** that how to get video path in activity to play video

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = getIntent();   
Uri tmpSelectedImageUri = i.getData(); 
filename = getPath(tmpSelectedImageUri, ViewVideo.this); 

 public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) { 
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };    
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);    
    int column_index =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    return cursor.getString(column_index); 
}
```

It work for me.

Comment: when i open video in  my player from whats app it throw null pointer exception. At  line Uri tmpSelectedImageUri = i.getData();

when i open video in my player from gallery then it work fine.

Any idea what should i do?